# With Khinchine's inequality, prove Fourier basis is unconditional in $L^{p}[0,1]$ only for $p=2$

Tags: banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to prove [Problem 6.10](https://books.google.com/books?id=d7EZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA165) in "Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis" by by Camil Muscalu and Wilhelm Schlag.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inO4O.jpg)

> **Problem 6.10.** Let $1\le p < \infty$ and suppose that there exists a constant $C(p)$ such that
> $$\sup_{\varepsilon_n=\pm1} \left\lVert \sum_{-N}^N \varepsilon_n \widehat f(n) e(n\theta) \right\rVert \le C(p) \|f\|_p \qquad \forall f\in L^p([0,1]), \forall N\ge1. \tag{6.33}$$
> Show that necessarily $p=2$. Next show that (6.33) is equivalent to the property that $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \varepsilon_n \widehat f(n) e(n\cdot)$ converges in $L^p([0,1])$ for each choice of signs $\varepsilon_n=\pm1$  and $f\in L^p([0,1])$. This latter property is called *unconditional convergence*, and this problem therefore amounts to proving that the exponential system is unconditional only for $p=2$. In Section 8.4 we shall see that Haar functions are unconditional on $L^p([0,1])$ for $1<p<\infty$. Hint: Use Khinchine's inequality

Here are some attempts,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\Big\|\sum_{n=-N}^N\epsilon_n\hat f(n)e(n\theta)\Big\|_p&=\mathbb{E}\Big(\int_0^1|\sum_{n=-N}^N\epsilon_n\hat f(n)e(n\theta)|^pd\theta\Big)^{1/p}\\
&\leq\Big(\mathbb{E}\int_0^1|\sum_{n=-N}^N\epsilon_n\hat f(n)e(n\theta)|^pd\theta\Big)^{1/p}\quad(\text{since $g(x)=x^{1/p}$ is concave for $p\geq1$})\\
&\leq C(\sum_{n=-N}^N|\hat f(n)|^2)^{1/2}\quad(\text{Khinchine's inequality})\\
&\leq C\|f\|_2
\end{align*}
But
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big\|\sum_{n=-N}^N\epsilon_n\hat f(n)e(n\theta)\Big\|_p\leq\sup_{\epsilon_n}\Big\|\sum_{n=-N}^N\epsilon_n\hat f(n)e(n\theta)\Big\|_p
$$
the inequality seems in the wrong direction. Any suggestion on how to do next? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find a proof in Chapter II.D of the book: Banach spaces for analysts, by P. Wojtaszczyk

Comment: Thanks for the reference!